# number of overlaps in sphere covering

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

I have a problem and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have the following conjecture:

For a set of spheres of arbitrary radii in $\mathbb{R}^d$, in which the center point of every sphere lies outside of every other sphere, there exists no region in the space that is overlapped by more than $2d$ spheres.

Is this right? Anyone have any thoughts on if a proof for this exists?

Thanks.

Comment: Just an observation, if we had such a bound $f(d)$, then we could always construct a covering of a set with volume $V$, using just $f(d)V/V(r)$ spheres, where $V(r)$ is the volume of the covering spheres. Maybe this is even what you want to use it for? In any case, there exists a high enough lower bound for the number of spheres needed to cover $V$, we know in effect that the overlap can be infinite.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample for $d=2$: You can place five open unit disks on the vertices of a pentagon of side length one. They overlap around the origin.

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you have any idea if _any_ bound on the number of overlapping spheres exists?

Comment: @user1574591 You might get a lower bound from the kissing numbers. If you can pack $n$ spheres with $\epsilon$ of margin outside a single sphere, then you can double their radius, such that they still don't contain each other's centers, but overlap in the center sphere.

Comment: That is, you can certainly always get $\text{kissing}(d)-1$ overlaps. I conjecture $\text{kissing}(d)$ is the maximum number of overlaps. Afaik [1] the best upper bounds for the kissing number is about $2^{d/5}$[1]. In any case the overlap can certainly be exponential in $d$.: http://www.math.bas.bg/serdica/2012/2012-507-522.pdf